# Is it possible to bind the size of an accordion dynamically to the size of the expanded titled pane in JavaFX-8?

Tags: size, javafx-8, accordion, changelistener

Such as the title suggests, i'm trying to bind the size of an `Accordion` dynamically to the size of the expanded `TitledPane`.

I tried to add an `ChangeListener` to the `expandedPaneProperty` of the `accordion` in the initialize method of the controller for the UI which contains the `Accordion` using following code:

```
private double prefHeight, prefWidth;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    prefHeight = acc.getPrefHeight(); //double variables of controller
    prefWidth = acc.getPrefWidth();
    acc.expandedPaneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>(){

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Object> observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            TitledPane pane = acc.getExpandedPane();
            if(pane != null){
                acc.setPrefHeight(prefHeight + pane.getPrefHeight());
                acc.setPrefWidth(prefWidth + pane.getPrefWidth());
            }

        }
    });
}
```

The Problem is, that this code leads to a `NullPointerException` at line 3, which might indicate that the property might not be instatiated at this moment. 
Update: Problem concerning `NullPointerException` was solved, i didn't initialized the `Accordion` properly. 
The code is still not working, though.

The corresponding FXML:

```
<Accordion fx:id="acc" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SettingsController">
  <panes>
    <TitledPane alignment="TOP_LEFT" animated="false" text="Alarm sound">
         <tooltip>
            <Tooltip text="Enables to choose an alarm sound." />
         </tooltip>
         <content>
            <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" styleClass="box">
               <children>
                  <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" styleClass="hbox">
                     <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reset to default" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveAndExitOnClick" text="Save and exit" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <ListView maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </content></TitledPane>
    <TitledPane animated="false" text="Style">
         <tooltip>
            <Tooltip text="Enables to choose a style for the program." />
         </tooltip>
         <content>
            <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" styleClass="box">
               <children>
                  <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" styleClass="h-box">
                     <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reset to default" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveAndExitOnClick" text="Save and exit" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <ListView maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </content></TitledPane>
      <TitledPane animated="false" text="Language">
         <tooltip>
            <Tooltip text="Enables to choose a style for the program." />
         </tooltip>
         <content>
            <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" styleClass="box">
               <children>
                  <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                     <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reset to default" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveAndExitOnClick" text="Save and exit" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <ListView maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </content>
      </TitledPane>
      <TitledPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" styleClass="box" text="Other settings">
         <content>
            <ToolBar maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" orientation="VERTICAL" styleClass="box">
              <items>
                <Button contentDisplay="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Recenter Window" />
                  <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reset program to default settings" />
                  <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Load custom alarm sound" />
                  <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Apply custom style" />
              </items>
            </ToolBar>
         </content>
      </TitledPane>
      <TitledPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="200.0" text="About">
         <content>
            <TextArea editable="false" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Timer Program, written by QBW.&#10;Version: &#10;&#10;Fonts: &#10;Font Awesome, License:&#10;&#10;Alarm sounds:&#10;&#10;&#10;Acknowledgement:&#10;·Hans-Peter Habelitz for &quot;Programmieren lernen mit Java&quot;&#10;&#10;·Christian Ullenboom for &quot;Java ist auch eine Insel&quot; and &quot;Java SE8 Standardbibliothek&quot;&#10;&#10;·Anton Epple for &quot;JavaFX 8 - Grundlagen und fortgeschrittene Techniken&quot;&#10;&#10;·The stackoverflow.com community&#10;&#10;· Creators of alarm sound files:&#10;     ·&#10;     ·&#10;     ·&#10;     ·&#10;     ·&#10;· Creators of Font awesome&#10;" wrapText="true" />
         </content>
         <tooltip>
            <Tooltip text="Contains information about the program, its creator and license information" />
         </tooltip>
      </TitledPane>
  </panes>
</Accordion>
```

How is it possible to solve that problem?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. If you set the height of the `Accordion` to the size of the currently displayed `TitledPane` the headers will not be visible anymore. What working are you looking for?

Comment: I want to achieve that the accordion only occupy as much space as it needs to display the active pane and the headers of the other TitledPanes. 
But you are right, about the behaviour the accordion, i did not thought about that. I updated the code, but it's still not working and i do not know exactly why.